Story about 2 people who can teleport, who are fighting, by teleporting behind the each other to kill their opponent
Seeing a previous question about "Jaunting" reminded me of this story.
Probably from the 80s, probably a short story.
Two people are fighting, I believe they are part of a larger force (i.e. they are solders) but can't remember positively. I don't think it was fantasy, it seems like it was more of a modern combat type situation.
When one of them (A) spots the other (B), "A" teleports to behind "B" and gets ready to kill him, (with a sword, or spear, or maybe even just reach around and slash his throat with a knife) but "B" realizes what "A" has done, and teleports behind "A" and gets ready to kill "A" in the same manner. Then there is a series of teleports as each one teleports behind the other and tries to kill him. In this fashion they are moving backwards across the field as they teleport a few feet behind the other.
I do not remember any more of this story or the outcome, just this scene where they continuously in a fraction of a second teleport to behind the other and try to kill them. Only for the other to teleport behind them in a fraction of a second. I think they might have been doing it faster and faster.

This sounds like the "temporal fugue" between the Steel General and Wakim in Creatures of Light and Darkness but it's not a short story.

Definitely a story, and not a joke panel from a manga? (Busou Renkin)

Bleach did the same joke once too.

The obvious thing to do is teleport just a half metre behind your opponent with your sword already outstretched forward. The sword then materialises inside your opponent instantly delivering the fatal blow.

This is a great description of the ending of Simon Hawke’s The Ivanhoe Gambit
It dates from the early 90s, and is a short novel - around 200 pages.
The climax has the hero and protagonist engaged in a sword battle. At one point, one of them makes an error, leaving himself open to a counter; so he shifts himself in time so he can counter the blow that would have killed him, so his opponent shifts to counter the counter, and so on.
By the end, there’s dozens of iterations of each, and the fight only ends when the pattern is interrupted by an outsider.

I have read this book. Will look to see if I can find a copy to check it out.

I could have sworn what I remembered was personal teleport ability, as opposed to an instrument doing the teleporting, but don't recall it well enough to be sure. So I am going to accept this one as correct.

It's the originator of the term "temporal fugue" and, although originally published in 1969 it was regularly republished into the 1980s.  Creatures of Light and Darkness by the inimitable Roger Zelazny:

Thirty seconds ago, Wakim is standing behind the General and Wakim is standing before the General, and the Wakim who stands behind, who has just arrived in that instant, clasps his hands together and raises them for a mighty blow upon that metal helm—
—while thirty-five seconds ago, the Steel General appears behind the Wakim of that moment of Time, draws back his hand and swings it—
—while the Wakim of thirty seconds ago, seeing himself in fugue, delivering his two-handed blow, is released to vanish, which he does, into a time ten seconds before, when he prepares to emulate his future image observed—
—as the General of thirty-five seconds before the point of attack sees himself draw back his hand, and vanishes to a time twelve seconds previously....


Not a short story, but is a short (and excellent) book. First thing I thought of seeing the questions title.

Not sure if I have read this.
